# Java Number-Guessing Program Stalling Part-way Through

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in programming and am building a Java number guessing game for a college semester project.  Here's a description of it:

> Design a game where each player picks a number.  One player is the
>   user and the other is the computer.  The players take turns guessing
>   the window range of the number or the number.  If the player selects
>   the correct range, it costs a turn.  If the player selects an
>   incorrect range, it costs 2 turns.  If the player tries to guess the
>   number it does not cost a turn.  The game ends when the player guesses
>   the correct number.

Below is the code I have written so far.  Specifically I am I struggling with getting the program to continue after the details about each player are entered into the "players" array.  Any suggestions for how I can adjust the code so that the program continues on to the next steps after the players enter their info?  Thanks for your ideas!

Game class:

```
package guessmynumber_2;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Game {
public static void playGame() {
    /**
     * The total number of players (combined number of human and computer
     * players)
     */
    int numPlayers;

    //Scanner object
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Welcome message
    System.out.println("Welcome to Guess My Number Version 1.0.1!");

    //Store user's input
    String userInput;

    //Get number rounds
    System.out.print("This game will be best of: ");
    userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
    int bestOf = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    if (bestOf < 1) {
        System.out.print("Enter a valid number of rounds: ");
        userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
        bestOf = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    }

    //Get the upper limit of the game
    System.out.print("This game is between 1 and: ");
    userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
    int upperGameLimit = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    while (upperGameLimit < 2) {
        System.out.print("Enter a valid, nonnegative upper limit of the game greater than 1: ");
        userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
        upperGameLimit = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    }


    //Determine number of players
    System.out.print("Enter the number of players: ");
    userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
    numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

    //Input validation loop
    while (numPlayers < 1) {
        System.out.print("Enter a valid number of players: ");
        userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
        numPlayers = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    }

    //Make an array of players
    Player[] players = new Player[numPlayers];

    //Initiate an instance of each of the players
    for (int playerIndex = 0; playerIndex < players.length; playerIndex++) {

        //Call Constructor
        players[playerIndex] = new Player();

        //Ask for player type
        System.out.print("Specify Player " + (playerIndex + 1) + "'s Type: Computer(c) or Human(h): ");
        userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
        String playerType = userInput;

        //Input Validation Loop
        while (!(playerType.equalsIgnoreCase("Computer")
                || playerType.equalsIgnoreCase("Human")
                || playerType.equalsIgnoreCase("c")
                || playerType.equalsIgnoreCase("h"))) {
            System.out.print("Specify a valid identity for player " + playerType + ": Computer (c) or Human (h)");
            userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
            playerType = userInput;
        }
        //Set the player type in the player object
        switch (playerType) {
            case "Human":
            case "human":
            case "H":
            case "h":
                players[playerIndex].setPlayerType("human");
                break;
            case "Computer":
            case "computer":
            case "C":
            case "c":
                players[playerIndex].setPlayerType("computer");
                break;
            default:
            //No default operation
        }

        //Ask for player's name and secret number if player type is player.
        //Get computer's random secret number
        if (players[playerIndex].getPlayerType().equalsIgnoreCase("human")) {
            System.out.print("Enter Player " + (playerIndex + 1) + "'s name: ");
            String playerName = keyboard.nextLine();
            //Check if player specified name
            if (playerName.equals("")) {
                playerName = "Player " + (playerIndex + 1);
            }
            players[playerIndex].setName(playerName);

            //Ask for player's secret number
            System.out.print(players[playerIndex].getName() + ", enter your secret number: ");
            userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
            int secretNumber = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
            //Input validation loop
            while (secretNumber <= 0 || secretNumber > upperGameLimit) {

                System.out.print("Invalid number.  Enter a positive, "
                        + "nonzero integer that is less than or equal to "
                        + upperGameLimit + ": ");
                userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
                secretNumber = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
            }
            players[playerIndex].setSecretNumber(secretNumber);

        } else {
            Random randomNumber = new Random();
            int computerNumber = randomNumber.nextInt(upperGameLimit);
            players[playerIndex].setSecretNumber(computerNumber);
        }



        //Set which player this player is against
        int against;
        if (playerIndex == (players.length - 1)) {
            against = 0;
        } else {
            against = (playerIndex + 1);
        }
        players[playerIndex].setAgainst(against);

    }



    boolean gameOver = false;
    //Loop through each round
    for (int round = 1; round <= bestOf; round++) {
        //Loop through each turn
        while (!gameOver) {
            //Loop through each player
            for (int playerIndex = 0; playerIndex < players.length; playerIndex++) {
                if (players[playerIndex].getTurnPenalty() != 0) {


                    //Get user number guess
                    System.out.print(players[playerIndex].getName() + ": Guess "
                            + players[players[playerIndex].getAgainst()].getName() + "'s number: ");
                    userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
                    int userGuess = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
                    //Input validation loop
                    while (userGuess < 1 || userGuess > upperGameLimit) {
                        System.out.print("Invalid guess.  Enter a number between 1 and " + upperGameLimit + ": ");
                        userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
                        userGuess = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
                    }

                } else {
                    players[playerIndex].decrementTurnPenalty();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

Player Class:

```
package guessmynumber_2;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class Player {

    //Fields

    /**
     * The player's score
     */
    private int score;
    /**
     * The penalty for guessing incorrect windows
     */
    private int turnPenalty;
    /**
     * The number the player chose
     */
    private int secretNumber;
    /**
     * The player's name
     */
    private String name;
    /**
     * Human or computer
     */
    private String playerType;
    /**
     * The player index this player is against
     */
    private int against;

    //Setters and getters
    /**
     * @return the score
     */
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    /**
     * @param score the score to set
     */
    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    /**
     * @return the turnPenalty
     */
    public int getTurnPenalty() {
        return turnPenalty;
    }

    /**
     * @param turnPenalty the turnPenalty to set
     */
    public void setTurnPenalty(int turnPenalty) {
        this.turnPenalty = turnPenalty;
    }

    /**
     * @return the secretNumber
     */
    public int getSecretNumber() {
        return secretNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param secretNumber the secretNumber to set
     */
    public void setSecretNumber(int secretNumber) {
        this.secretNumber = secretNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the playerType
     */
    public String getPlayerType() {
        return playerType;
    }

    /**
     * @param playerType the playerType to set
     */
    public void setPlayerType(String playerType) {
        this.playerType = playerType;
    }
    /**
     * @return the against
     */
    public int getAgainst() {
        return against;
    }

    /**
     * @param against the against to set
     */
    public void setAgainst(int against) {
        this.against = against;
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Player(){
        score = 0;
        name = "";
        playerType = "";
        secretNumber = 1;
        against = 0;
    }
    //Methods
    public int decrementTurnPenalty(){
        return turnPenalty - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
playerType = userInput;
    }   <<<------------------ I believe that this curly bracket schouldn't be here? Check the for loop.
    //Set the player type in the player object
    switch (playerType) {
```

It encloses the for loop straight after the while, whereas I think it should enclose all the switch statements too.

Comment: That curly brace is in there to close up the input validation loop that ensures that a proper player type is entered by the user.

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble, but that curly brace seems to be for the while loop only, not the enclosing for loop

Comment: Fixed the issue.  It was in this line:

Comment: //Loop through each player
                for (int playerIndex = 0; playerIndex < players.length; playerIndex++) {
                    if (players[playerIndex].getTurnPenalty() == 0) {                                                                         I had an != instead of ==, which messed up the logic.

Comment: @user2976453 Feel free to post that as an answer